# API. Лучший способ вернуть ответ после выполнения джоба

Tags: api, ruby-on-rails, запрос

Клиент должен передать свой файл используя API ендпоинт и в качестве ответа получить обработанный файл обратно. Файл должен обработаться в джобе (Sidekiq).

Но есть нюанс. Сервер не должен хранить какой-либо информации о переданных пользователями файлах.

Поскольку плохо было бы заставлять клиента ждать полного выполнения джоба, я ищу всевозможные способы реализации такого случая.

Comment: Обычно в таком случае результат шлют на почту